# function call 'clear_all_cache' and 'clear_assign' is unknown or deprecated. error in smarty?

Tags: php, variables, caching, smarty

I need to remove the cache when a user change language, but I get an error message.

```
  $smarty = new Smarty;
 //$smarty->force_compile = true;
 $smarty->debugging = true;
 $smarty->caching = false;
 $smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;

 if (isset($_COOKIE['country'])) 
  {
 $country = $_COOKIE['country'];

  $language = "eng";

 if ($country == "NO"){    
  $language = "nor";

  $smarty->clear_all_cache();
  }      
 }
```

I also get this message when i use clear_assign:

```
function call 'clear_assign' is unknown or deprecated
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have recently upgrade your Smarty to version 3.x.x
some method names are changed

in your case "clear_assign" is changed to "clearAssign"

for more information get offline documentation of "Smarty 3.0.x" from [HERE](http://www.smarty.net/files/docs/manual-en-3.0.zip)
or online documentation from [HERE](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/)